# Binary Search Tree, delete node

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am writing a program that reads in a "student record" if you will and then separates it into 4 binary search trees based on the data. I am attempting to delete a node, but instead of actually removing it, I would just like to set a flag within the struct which basically lets me know that it has been "deleted". This is my code and it is giving me several errors:

```
 void deleteNode( TreeNodePtr *treePtr, SREC R, unsigned long key)/*ADD HOW*/
 {
    printf("I got into the delete function.\n");

     /*empty*/
    if(*treePtr != NULL)
    {
        if(R.SID<(*treePtr)->SID)/*Not empty*/
        {
            printf("less than\n");
            deleteNode((*treePtr)->leftPtr, R, key);
        }
        else if(R.SID>(*treePtr)->SID)
        {
            printf("more than.\n");
            deleteNode((*treePtr)->rightPtr, R, key);
        }
        else
        {
            treePtr->exists = 1;
            printf("Are we deleted yet?\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
         fprintf(stderr,"Could not locate student with ID.\n");
    }
 }
```

The errors are :
    note: expected ‘struct treeNode **’ but argument is of type ‘struct treeNode *’
     error: ‘struct treeNode’ has no member named ‘SID’.
I am sure I am just missing some little thing but I don't know what it is. 
Any ideas?

Comment: And your structure definitions are:

Comment: What's the point of `key`?

Comment: Also show us the definition for the types `TreeNodePtr` and `SREC`.

Comment: "I am just missing some little thing" -- No, actually you're missing the fundamentals. You need to learn what pointers are and how they work, and a lot more.

Comment: Compare [this](http://ideone.com/TTUruA) with [that](http://ideone.com/d2DsiH).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
deleteNode((*treePtr)->leftPtr, R, key);
```

into

```
deleteNode(&(*treePtr)->leftPtr, R, key);
```

Same for right. It's questionable if you really want the function to take a `**` though. a `*` would work just as well when you're not actually deleting.

For the second error, you most likely have a member in `struct treeNode` of type `SREC`. You have to infix that member name, e.g. `(*treePtr)->R.SID`.

Comment: And how is `treePtr->exists = 1;` supposed to work? The OP is confused about pointers vs. pointers to pointers, and needs to learn how to name things properly and to use temp variables to avoid unreadable and overly expensive code scattered with double derefs.

Answer (score 0):

> The errors are : note: expected ‘struct treeNode **’ but argument is
>   of type ‘struct treeNode *’ error: ‘struct treeNode’ has no member
>   named ‘SID’

These errors mean just what they say. The first parameter of `deleteNode` is of type `TreeNodePtr *`, aka `struct treeNode **`, but you're passing `(*treePtr)->leftPtr`, which is of type `TreeNodePtr`, aka `struct treeNode *`. And you reference (*treePtr)->SID but there's no such member of `struct treeNode`.

You should also be getting an error for

```
treePtr->exists = 1;
```

because treePtr points to a *pointer* to a `struct treeNode`, but pointers don't have members. And why is your "deleted" flag called "exists"? That's backwards. Either call it `deleted`, or set it to 0 and initialize it to 1. The former is better.

And what's your `key` parameter for? You never use it.

Here's something that might work, assuming that `TreeNode` contains an `SREC` called `R`, and a `deleted` flag:

```
void markDeleted(TreeNode* pnode, SREC R)
{
    if (pnode == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not locate student with ID.\n");
    }
    else if (R.SID < pnode->R.SID)
    {
        /* search left branch */
        markDeleted(pnode->leftPtr, R);
    }
    else if (R.SID > pnode->R.SID)
    {
        /* search right branch */
        markDeleted(pnode->rightPtr, R);
    }
    else
    {
        /* match */
        pnode->deleted = 1;
    }
}
```